# Attaching data file (.csv, .json) as part of a setup package to be used on Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to use dataflow to complete a task that requires the use of a .csv and .json files. From what I understand, I should be able to create a setup.py file that will include these files and distribute them to multiple workers.

This is how my files are laid out:

```
pipline.py
setup.py
utils /
  -->__init__.py
  -->**CSV.csv**
  -->**JSON.json**
```

This is my setup.py file:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name='utils',
                 version='0.0.1',
                 description='utils',
                 packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
                 package_data={'utils': ['**CSV.csv**', '**JSON.json**']},
                 include_package_data=True)
```

This is my bean.DoFn functions:

```
class DoWork(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):

        import pandas as pd

        df_csv = pd.read_csv('**CSV.csv**')
        df_json = pd.read_json('**JSON.json**')

        Do other stuff with dataframes

        yield [stuff]
```

My pipeline is setup like so:

```
dataflow_options = ['--job_name=pipline',
                    '--project=pipeline',
                    '--temp_location=gs://pipeline/temp',
                    '--staging_location=gs://pipeline/stage',
                    '--setup_file=./setup.py']

options = PipelineOptions(dataflow_options)
gcloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    update = p | beam.Create(files) | beam.ParDo(DoWork())
```

Basically I keep getting an:

```
IOError: File CSV.csv does not exist
```

It doesn't think the .json file exists either but is just erroring out before it reaches that step. The files are possibly not making it to dataflow or I am referencing them incorrectly within the DoFn. Should I actually be putting the files into data_files parameter of the setup function instead of package_data?

Answer (score 0):

you need to upload the input files in gs and give a gs location rather than **CSV**. I think you ran the code locally having the csv file in the same directory as the code. But running it using DataflowRunner will need the files in gs.

Comment: If I put the .csv in google storage, would I even need to use the setup.py file?

Comment: No, you don't need the setup.py file just to package the csv files. you have to use setuptools for the external libray dependencies. beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies. If you really need the CSV file, please also try adding data_files section in the setup.py and refer to the file in you code using Path(__file__).parent / 'somefile.json'
with path.open() as fp:
    json.load(fp)